# How to visualize a GraphML multitree?

Tags: data-visualization, software, graph-theory

I have a multitree that represents the lineages of all the fishgroups in a breeding program. It's stored as a double adjacency table with `fish_id`, `sire_id` and `dam_id`. This means a particular fishgroup is only directly aware of its parents (if any) and knows nothing about descendents.  I can conveniently output this data as a [GraphML](http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/primer/graphml-primer.html) doc, but I'm having difficulty finding a viewer that can display a multitree given simple input. [InfoVis](http://thejit.org/) can, but requires a verbose and redundant description of the structure. [Cytoscape Web](http://cytoscapeweb.cytoscape.org/) can take GraphML objects, but can't automatically layout a multitree (it does it's best, but I'd like a hierarchical layout). Does anyone know of another option?

My GraphML looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<graphml xmlns="http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns 
        http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns/1.0/graphml.xsd">
    <key id="currentfish" for="node" attr.name="cfish" attr.type="string">
        <default>#ffff00</default>
    </key>
    <key id="parcount" for="edge" attr.name="parcount" attr.type="int"></key>
    <key id="parenttype" for="edge" attr.name="parenttype" attr.type="string"></key>
    <key id="fish" for="node" attr.name="fish" attr.type='string'></key>
    <graph id="G" edgedefault="directed">
        <node id='f22'>
            <data key='fishname'>ZS6181</data>
        </node>
        <edge id='es_23' source='f57' target='f23'>
            <data key='parcount'>0</data>
            <data key='parenttype'>sire</data>
        </edge>
        <node id='f23'>
            <data key='fishname'>90716</data>
        </node>
        <edge id='ed_23' source='f42' target='f23'>
            <data key='parcount'>0</data>
            <data key='parenttype'>dam</data>
        </edge>
        <node id='f24'>
            <data key='fishname'>ZS6377</data>
        </node>
        <node id='f25'>
            <data key='fishname'>ZS6375</data>
        </node>
        <edge id='ed_26' source='f25' target='f26'>
            <data key='parcount'>10</data>
            <data key='parenttype'>dam</data>
        </edge>
        <node id='f26'>
            <data key='fishname'>ZS6375 F1</data>
        </node>
        <edge id='es_26' source='f25' target='f26'>
            <data key='parcount'>10</data>
            <data key='parenttype'>sire</data>
        </edge>
        <node id='f27'>
            <data key='fishname'>ZS56181 F1</data>
        </node>
        <edge id='es_27' source='f43' target='f27'>
            <data key='parcount'>9</data>
            <data key='parenttype'>sire</data>
        </edge>
        <edge id='ed_27' source='f43' target='f27'>
            <data key='parcount'>9</data>
            <data key='parenttype'>dam</data>
        </edge>
        <node id='f28'>
            <data key='fishname'>ZS6377 F1</data>
        </node>
        <edge id='es_28' source='f44' target='f28'>
            <data key='parcount'>7</data>
            <data key='parenttype'>sire</data>
        </edge>
        <edge id='ed_28' source='f44' target='f28'>
            <data key='parcount'>7</data>
            <data key='parenttype'>dam</data>
        </edge>
        <node id='f29'>
            <data key='fishname'>100128 AB</data>
        </node>
        <edge id='es_30' source='f25' target='f30'>
            <data key='parcount'>10</data>
            <data key='parenttype'>sire</data>
        </edge>
        <node id='f30'>
            <data key='fishname'>ZS6375 F1A</data>
        </node>
        <edge id='ed_30' source='f25' target='f30'>
            <data key='parcount'>10</data>
            <data key='parenttype'>dam</data>
        </edge>
        <edge id='ed_31' source='f45' target='f31'>
            <data key='parcount'>0</data>
            <data key='parenttype'>dam</data>
        </edge>
        <node id='f31'>
            <data key='fishname'>AB 100223</data>
        </node>
        <edge id='es_31' source='f25' target='f31'>
            <data key='parcount'>0</data>
            <data key='parenttype'>sire</data>
        </edge>
        <edge id='es_32' source='f45' target='f32'>
            <data key='parcount'>0</data>
            <data key='parenttype'>sire</data>
        </edge>
        <edge id='ed_32' source='f45' target='f32'>
            <data key='parcount'>0</data>
            <data key='parenttype'>dam</data>
        </edge>
        <node id='f32'>
            <data key='fishname'>AB 100319</data>
        </node>
        <edge id='es_33' source='f32' target='f33'>
            <data key='parcount'>8</data>
            <data key='parenttype'>sire</data>
        </edge>
        <edge id='ed_33' source='f31' target='f33'>
            <data key='parcount'>8</data>
            <data key='parenttype'>dam</data>
        </edge>
        <node id='f33'>
            <data key='fishname'>AB 100714</data>
        </node>
        <edge id='ed_34' source='f28' target='f34'>
            <data key='parcount'>10</data>
            <data key='parenttype'>dam</data>
        </edge>
        <node id='f34'>
            <data key='fishname'>AB 100715</data>
        </node>
        <edge id='es_34' source='f59' target='f34'>
            <data key='parcount'>10</data>
            <data key='parenttype'>sire</data>
        </edge>
        <edge id='ed_35' source='f27' target='f35'>
            <data key='parcount'>4</data>
            <data key='parenttype'>dam</data>
        </edge>
        <node id='f35'>
            <data key='fishname'>AB 100722</data>
        </node>
        <edge id='es_35' source='f28' target='f35'>
            <data key='parcount'>5</data>
            <data key='parenttype'>sire</data>
        </edge>
        <node id='f36'>
            <data key='fishname'>ZS6377 F2</data>
        </node>
        <edge id='es_36' source='f28' target='f36'>
            <data key='parcount'>8</data>
            <data key='parenttype'>sire</data>
        </edge>
        <edge id='ed_36' source='f28' target='f36'>
            <data key='parcount'>6</data>
            <data key='parenttype'>dam</data>
        </edge>
        <node id='f37'>
            <data key='fishname'>ZS6375 F2</data>
        </node>
        <node id='f38'>
            <data key='fishname'>100730 AB</data>
        </node>
        <edge id='es_39' source='f34' target='f39'>
            <data key='parcount'>6</data>
            <data key='parenttype'>sire</data>
        </edge>
        <edge id='ed_39' source='f38' target='f39'>
            <data key='parcount'>6</data>
            <data key='parenttype'>dam</data>
        </edge>
        <node id='f39'>
            <data key='fishname'>110208</data>
        </node>
        <node id='f40'>
            <data key='fishname'>110412</data>
        </node>
        <edge id='ed_41' source='f27' target='f41'>
            <data key='parcount'>2</data>
            <data key='parenttype'>dam</data>
        </edge>
        <node id='f41'>
            <data key='fishname'>110413</data>
        </node>
        <edge id='es_41' source='f24' target='f41'>
            <data key='parcount'>5</data>
            <data key='parenttype'>sire</data>
        </edge>
        <node id='f42'>
            <data key='fishname'>90318</data>
        </node>
        <node id='f43'>
            <data key='fishname'>ZS56181-90705</data>
        </node>
        <node id='f44'>
            <data key='fishname'>ZS6377-90913</data>
        </node>
        <node id='f45'>
            <data key='fishname'>ZS56181</data>
        </node>
        <node id='f57'>
            <data key='fishname'>90317</data>
        </node>
        <node id='f59'>
            <data key='fishname'>ZS63775 F1</data>
        </node>
    </graph>
</graphml>
```

Comment: Gephi
http://gephi.org/users/quick-start/

Comment: I ended up extending the PHP class Image_GraphViz, http://pear.php.net/package/Image_GraphViz/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried [GraphViz](http://www.graphviz.org/)?  Here is a [tutorial](http://blog.lome.pl/graphs/visualizing-graphml-file-with-graphviz/) and using GraphML.

Comment: The tutorial link is obsoleted, pls refer to https://web.archive.org/web/20120112003919/http://blog.lome.pl/graphs/visualizing-graphml-file-with-graphviz instead.